# Is there any way to send data as object instead of Parameter in Alamofire?

Tags: json, swift, parameters, alamofire

I want to send data like this:

```
{ "userName" : username,"password" : password,"city" : [ {"name":name, "address":address ,"lat":lat } , {"name":name ,"address":address ,"lat":lat }]}
```

But, Alamofire just accepts Parameter which is like this:

```
[ "userName" : username, "password" : password,"city" : [ ["name":name, "address":address ,"lat":lat ] , ["name":name ,"address":address ,"lat":lat ]]]
```

Even when I send data like below:

```
[ "userName" : username, "password" : password, "city" : [{"name":name, "address":address ,"lat":lat } , {"name":name ,"address":address ,"lat":lat }]]
```

And, it doesn't accept `JSON` type as city value which is in my data!

I get the error: reason: `'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'`
does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put parameters in dictionary and set encoding in alamofire request method to JsonEncoding.default

Comment: Please check response code then print response from server to see if you have sent correct parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can send encodable objects through alamofire by passing it to the parameters argument like this: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#request-parameters-and-parameter-encoders

So you can create a swift struct describing your data:

```swift
struct Something: Codable {
    let userName: String
    let password: String
    let city: [City]
}

struct City: Codable {
    let name: String
    let address: String
    let lat: String
}
```

then create objects like this with your data to send through alamofire:

```swift
let encodableObject = Something(userName: userName, password: password, city: [City(name: name, address: address, lat: lat)])

AF.request("www.someApiEndpoint.com", method: method, parameters: encodableObject, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.prettyPrinted, headers: headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension.

Create an object with encodable protocol applied.

```
struct JSON {
    static let encoder = JSONEncoder()
}

extension Encodable {
    
    subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
        return dictionary[key]
    }
    
    // Convert an Encodable Object into dictionary
    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        get {
            return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSON.encoder.encode(self))) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
        }
    }
    
}
```

Create your encodable object and use `dictionary` getter so it would return the dictionary for you automatically. Here's the example of a request function.

```
func postWithHeader<T>(url : String, params : T?, onCompletion : @escaping (Data?, NetworkError?)->Void) where T : Encodable {
        print("----------> URL : \(url)")
        print("            Params  : \(String(describing: params?.dictionary ?? nil))")

        session.request(url, method: .post, parameters: (params).dictionary, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: getHeader()).responseData { response in
            print("<---------- URL : \(url)")
            NetworkManager.printData(response: response)
    }
}
```

Well its not sending the whole object because the alamofire wont allow it. So we have to improvise a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Login: Encodable {
    let email: String
    let password: String
}

let login = Login(email: "test@test.test", password: "testPassword")

AF.request("https://httpbin.org/post",
           method: .post,
           parameters: login,
           encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default).response { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

You may find other examples on Alamofire GitHub repo: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#request-parameters-and-parameter-encoders